# Where is the JavaScript of the "Add New Option" Button?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

I'm talking about the page at admin -> catalog -> manage products -> *any product* -> custom options tab. I customized this page and added a new button which I basically want to act similarly.
Presumably it is done via JavaScript, but it isn't clear to me where this functionality is defined.

A pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/option.phtml`.
I think that one contains the js for the custom options.
Look specially at the function `productOption.add`. That's the one that adds a new option.
The add event is binded to the add button through this

```
if($('<?php echo $this->getAddButtonId() ?>')){
    Event.observe('<?php echo $this->getAddButtonId() ?>', 'click', productOption.add.bind(productOption));
}
```

Comment: Yess... I tried that, did nothing. Turns out I had forgotten to override the original file, so the things I tested had no chance of being used. Thanks man, pointed me back in the right direction :)