# Custom option button does nothing

Tags: magento-1.9, product, custom-options

I have a problem adding a custom option to product. When I click on the "Add New Option" button nothing happens? And I have no clue why its happening. Any help would be highly appreciated.

The bug exists on all products, magento 1.9[image]

Comment: This might be useful http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46356/where-is-the-javascript-of-the-add-new-option-button

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same issue, I found that disabling modules one by one until the custom option could be added worked.

For me it turned out to be Magecomp Absolute Pricing that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This very likely is a JavaScript bug. Try to open The Developer toolbar (`F12` in Firefox or Google Chrome) to check for any JavaScript error messages.

If there are any try to figure out what causes the problem - you could then try to disable all custom/community modules one after the other. Disable the cache when trying that.

Also, it could help to reinstall the Core Modules through Magento Connect - you should only do that if you're really sure you haven't modified any core files (Core, template, translation, etc files) since this will overwrite the complete kernel.

Comment: we change the interface locale language to english and the fix the problem. I dont know why but before the custom buttom was working with the french interface.